# How to reference the .EDMX model of another project?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I've got a problem and I don't know how to fix it!

Let me explain:

In my solution I have a folder named "Data" with a project called Repository. Inside this project is my .EDMX file.

Now I have a Folder named Logic with a Project called Management. I added a reference to the Repository project and I copied the connection string for the .edmx into the appconfig from my Management project. But when I try to use the context in the Management project it says that It couldn't find a connection string named RCDOKUEntities. But It's definitely in the appconfig

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I had to put the whole connection string into the appconfig of the startup project.